# DVD tray opens after suspend, at boot after recent kernel updates

Tags: dvd

The DVD tray opens and remains open after suspend, at boot.

20.04.3 LTS
currently the -86 kernel, problem began with -84

ASUS M4A88TD-M

I see this problem being discussed in other Linux versions but not here?? Is this problem being addressed or should I figure out how to backtrack to older kernel as others have done to fix this issue?

Comment: This problem was reported to Launchpad as [Bug #1942299](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1942299).

Comment: Fixed with today's -88 kernel. Sincere thanks to those of you devoting time to bug swatting and supporting fairly clueless linux converts.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on 20.04.3 LTS with kernel release 5.11.0-36-generic.  The fix has apparently already been scheduled into the update cycle. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1942299